# Convert Access Database to 97 format

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-97

Is there a way of converting an Access Database into a 97 file format, using Access 2007.
I know the GUI cant do it, and I have tried:

Application.ConvertAccessProject _
    SourceFilename:="C:\cCentre\Database\CommDBBad.mdb", _
    DestinationFilename:="C:\cCentre\Database\CommDB97.mdb", _
    DestinationFileFormat:=acFileFormatAccess97

Without luck.  Is there another method / tool ?

Thanks

Comment: can you use 'convertAccessProject' with a .mdb file?

Comment: Philippe, yes, you can.  A2003 help example specifically shows an MDB.  The confusion arises because the Access product group uses project terminology in a few places in MDBs as well as for the ADP general technology.

Answer (score 2):

According to this http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/HA102308221033.aspx you can only go back to Access 2000.  Then you need a copy of Access 2003 or 2000 to further convert it back to Access 97.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try DBEngine.CompactDatabase olddb, newdb,, dbVersion30

I can't test this myself due to a problem with A2007 on my system caused by some NTFS permissions corruptions problem.

Testing an empty A2000 database inside A2003 gives the following message:
 3301 Cannot perform this operation; features in this version are not available in databases with older formats.
so this probably won't work.